# Why destructor is called twice?

Tags: c++, class, object, destructor

I have the following code:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A
{
    int a, b;
public:
    A() : A(5, 7) {}
    A(int i, int j)
    {
        a = i;
        b = j;
    }
    A operator+(int x)
    {
        A temp;
        temp.a = a + x;
        temp.b = b + x;
        return temp;
    }
    ~A() { cout << a << " " << b << endl; }
};

int main()
{
    A a1(10, 20), a2;
    a2 = a1 + 50;
}
```

Output it shows:

```
60 70
60 70
10 20
```

The code works almost as expected. The problem is it prints the values of object `a2` twice... that means the destructor is called twice... but why it is called twice?

Comment: You forgot that `temp` is also an object.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Well, that's probably RVO'd. But the temporary created by `a1+50` can't be elided.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

During the assignment `a2=a1+50`, a temporary object containing `a1+50` is allocated.

This object is destroyed immediately after it is copied into `a2`.

Answer (score 7):

Because the `operator+` you defined returns a temporary object that is subsequently assigned to `a2`. Both the temporary and `a2` get destroyed (the temporary at the end of the statement, `a2` at the end of `main`), printing their values.

Answer (score 2):

Replace

```
a2=a1+50;
```

with just

```
a1+50;
```

and you will see why.